# DIY: Video Streaming Server

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming

I'm looking for any modern resources for setting up a video streaming server. Preferably open source solutions.

My searching on this has lead to a lot of dead ends. I also do need to build my own instead of paying for a service.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To setup your own video streaming server you should get started with the following components:

1. A linux distribution you are familiar with
2. A free and open source server solution such as [NaviServer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/naviserver/files/)
3. FFMpeg (see the [streaming guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide))

   - Reeoncode certain files / streams into desired resolutions/codecs etc.
   - Prepare streams for correct restreaming
4. VLC (see their [wiki](https://wiki.videolan.org/Streaming/#Using_the_commandline))

   - Prepare streams for correct restreaming (RTSP, UDP, HTTP, HTTP-LIVE, DASH)
   - Prepare files for correct restreaming
5. Maybe a content management solution to serve your streams such as [OpenACS](http://openacs.org/)

However, please note: Your question is very broad, hence this broad answer.

It really depends on your requirements and your given infrastructure. You will need to script tasks such as preparing streams for HTTP Live Streaming or other formats. If possible maybe add some more details to your questions (formats, codecs, platforms, file restreaming or stream restreaming, real-time etc.)

Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29771152/693052) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348741/693052) (long answer) for more input on HTTP Live Streaming.

Hopefully this will lead you to useful directions.

Answer (score 2):

Simple the best :
VideoLAN is a project that develops software for playing video and other media formats across a local area network (LAN)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VideoLAN
http://www.videolan.org/vlc/

Comment: What if I need to stream over http as well?

Comment: Follow the guidelines : http://www.tomsguide.com/faq/id-2363626/stream-videos-internet-vlc.html

Comment: If it's ok just selected it

Answer (score 2):

Use nginx mp4 module to stream videos. Limit bandwidth, concurrent connection, max buffer size and more. Use md5 key and ttl for security.

Answer (score 1):

Livebox has the linux distribution, VLC, Ffmpeg and everything installed for you.
It is a pre-built DIY video streaming server. See [livebox](https://livebox.co.in) for details.

Comment: Livebox is not a distro, is a commercial service offered by an India company

Answer (score 1):

There is a site (https://www.youphptube.com) a it's project on github (https://github.com/DanielnetoDotCom/YouPHPTube) for building your own video sharing site.

I didn't digged in this project, it may or may not be cool project.