# VLC HLS read input at native frame rate for real time streaming

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, vlc, http-live-streaming

I make http live streaming (hls) server with NodeJS. Now i have two variants: ffmpeg and VLC.
With ffmpeg I know command `-re` (*Read input at native frame rate. Mainly used to simulate a grab device or live input stream (e.g. when reading from a file)*). I need this for real time streaming (pseudo-live channel) from file.

As result I expected sign "Live" on the video player in browser, and not be able to make rewind over video (video.js player or hls.js library)

But how I can do this with VLC? Maybe you know some commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how I can do this with VLC? Maybe you know some commands?

Step 1: Use the livehttp module with VLC to restream your file source

```
vlc -vvv -I dummy <SOURCEADDRESS> --sout='#transcode{width=1280,height=720,fps=25,vcodec=h264,vb=4096,venc=x264{aud,profile=baseline,level=30,keyint=30,ref=1},acodec=mp3,ab=96}:std{access=livehttp{seglen=10,delsegs=false,numsegs=10,index=/path/to/your/index/prog_index.m3u8,index-url=YourUrl/fileSequence######.ts},mux=ts{use-key-frames},dst=/path/to/your/ts/files/fileSequence######.ts}'
```

Step 2: Publish your HTTP Live streaming playlist (m3u8) via HTML 5

```
<video>
 <source src="/path/to/your/index/prog_index.m3u8" />
</video>
```

This will produce a video player in HTML 5 without the possibility to rewind in your video, hence being "live" or "pseudo-live", whatever you want to call it.

See the following question details on [general architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35574998/693052) and a [longer explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348741/693052) on the environment involved

Comment: Thank you! It is exactly what I expected, also in good quality. But don't know why .ts files produced without sound. I think I can fix it. What part of your command responsible for reading input at native frame rate?