# Restream an existing live stream from an IP camera

Tags: streaming, h.264, vlc

As the title suggests, I'd like to re-stream an existing live stream (h264) to multiple clients over RTSP, from an IP camera. What is the best way to go about this? I have tried to do this using VLC, though so far, it hasn't worked.

> Method: 
>   - Media->Stream->Network
>   - Added ip camera stream url (rtsp://ip-address/xxxxx)
>   - next
>   - new destination -> RTSP (display locally)
>   - add - set port 8181 - set path /stream
>   - next
>   - disable transcoding

Have I made an obvious mistake here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using RTP or UDP and I would suggest to to try this via command line. Also, since you want to reach multiple clients, a multicast could prove useful.

I don't know which platform you are using. Here is a working command running on a Mac environment. You should be able to port this command to other platforms easily.

```
vlc -vvv $YOUR_INPUT_VIDEO_RTSP_URL --sout='#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=768,fps=25.0,width=1920,height=1080,scale=1,acodec=aac,ab=128,samplerate=32000}:standard{access=udp,mux=ts,dst=239.0.0.1}'
```

To view the stream you need to access the multicast address such as in:

```
vlc -vvv udp://@239.0.0.1
```

There are plenty of tutorials out there. Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348741/693052) explaining a bigger toolchain, however, it includes restreaming an RTSP IP camera stream. Also, read up on the Streaming How to guide over at VLC's [wiki](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/).

Hope this gets you going.