# vlc streaming not working on ubuntu

Tags: video-streaming, ubuntu-14.04, vlc, http-live-streaming

i'm trying to run vlc streaming between ubuntu machines.
I've tried with h264,mpeg and avi files but none seems to be working.

Error : main stream output error: stream chain failed for 'transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{dst=:8080/192.168.1.1}'
main input error : cannot start stream output instance ,aborting

kindly help me on this one.

Comment: This isn't a general tech helpdesk.

Comment: not sure, I am not able to find any

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few things you can do. However note, that as others have already commented - this isn't a general tech helpdesk. You would need to provide more details such a:

1. the complete streaming command including the input chain and output chain
2. some more lines before and after the error, which you can find in the log file.

Apart from that I would suggest to look into [VLC's forum](https://forum.videolan.org/viewforum.php?f=4&sid=47abeb332f9e1b8a483013d4517a2a9d) which has a separate stream-output forum. Also care to consult superuser's [vlc-media-player](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vlc-media-player). Last, stackoverflow should have the answer in form of a working example of a stream-output transcoding chain - which is what you seem to be looking for. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348741/693052) as a starting point.

Back to your actual question - try to format destination and port like this:

```
dst:192.168.1.1 port:8080
```