# How to get RTSP stream over web application

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, rtsp

Suppose this is my video stream URL:

```
rtsp://MyUserID:MyPassword@45.113.153.42:556/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0
```

The video stream works perfectly with VLC player but I want it to play it over my web application. Is there any possibility to play RTSP protocol in any web player?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I display an RTSP video stream in a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245040/how-can-i-display-an-rtsp-video-stream-in-a-web-page)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately playing an rtsp via your web browser is not that straight forward anymore.

**NPAPI Plugins are no longer supported**

This means in the end the VLC plugin for browsers is no longer supported. Firefox 52+ and other browser don't support it anymore. See this [announcement](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/npapi-plugins), basically stating that:

> "installed NPAPI plugins are no longer supported in Firefox, except
>   for Adobe Flash"

This also has been discussed on the [videolan Forum](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=134794), with no current solution.

**Use an old Mozilla Firefox ESR browser**

Still supports NPAPI plugins. However only until June 2018. Thus not really a future proof solution. Details on Firefox ESR can be found [here](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/faq/).

**A possible solution**

You could use HTML 5 with some other coding technology to transform your RTSP stream into let's say a segmented stream and deliver it via HTML 5 video tag. There is alot of solutions out there; look into posts from stackoverflow such as:

- [Streaming via RTSP in HTML 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1737065/693052)
- [VLC stream to chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348741/693052)
- [Display an RTSP video stream in a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2245040/693052) (similar to your question)

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Off course! 
You can use VLC player on your web app!!

This link had all the information that you need.

https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin/

In my experience this plugin is really fast a reliable